# hyperledger composer existing network install

Tags: hyperledger-composer

composer version v0.19.10
Fabric version 1.1
21 nodes:
  3 CLI
  3 CA
  3 orders
  3 www
  3 api
  6 peers
channel name: common

My fabric network is up and running and I can commit a transaction. But I am trying to add composer playground into the mix. If I try a default install it fails because it wants to use composerchannel. My question is. Is there an way to install composer to an existing fabric deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Composer Playground uses Business Connection Cards that it finds on your local file system. By default these are under a folder under your home folder e.g. `~/.composer`  (Maybe you have created a standard PeerAdmin card for a standard 1 peer Development Fabric? )

If you have already connected to the Fabric with Composer, you will have some cards that you already use to commit a transaction.  If you have separate machines you can use `composer card export` on the original machine and `composer card import` on the machine running Playground.

If you have not connected to the Fabric yet using Composer you might like to look at the [Composer Tutorial for MultiOrg](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) which goes through creating cards to connect Composer to the Fabric - it is not your exact scenario, but should provide enough information for you to move forward.

To answer the channel question, one of the files in the "Card" is a `connection.json` file and in that file the channel to use is specified. (By default composer uses a channel called composerchannel)